# What is the past simple and past participle of spit? Each online dictionary has different form

Tags: verbs, british-english, past-tense, past-participles, dictionaries

**Cambridge: past tense and past participle : here is the cambridge** link:spat.https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spit#british-1-1-2

Oxford:spits, spitting, spat, spitted
Oxford link :https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spit

Collins:spits, spitting, spat or spit
        Word forms: spits, spitting or spitted
Collins link:https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spit

Wikitionary:spitted,spitted
            spat/spit,spat/spit
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spit

Which one is correct?

Comment: One issue is that you've got two different words that both sound like "spit" in the bare infinitive; one means to project saliva or other matter out of your mouth, and the other means to skewer something with a pointy stick. The second is quite regular (that's the one that uses "spitted", always), so you might want to eliminate it from your question.

Comment: "Which one is correct?" is usually the wrong question about language.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be two separate verbs for spitting something from the mouth: the weak verb *spit* and the strong verb [*spete*](https://archive.org/stream/oed9aarch#page/n589/mode/2up), whose preterite and past participle were both *spat*. These verbs merged in the fifteenth century, leaving *spit* with the preterite and past participle of *spete*, which otherwise disappeared. Both forms, however, continue to be used: spit spit/spat spit/spat.

[Garner's *Modern English Usage*](https://books.google.de/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT2882&lpg=PT2882&dq=%22has%20spat%22&source=bl&ots=7xUjYNgCTl&sig=K0ptPufIcbgsQxP7_b28TCBLRS4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipgIC4_5bZAhWMZFAKHWqYAAAQ6AEwDXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22has%20spat%22&f=false) (2016) finds a decided preference for *spat* as the preterite, but less clarity with the past participle.  The verb *sit* may have also be of influence in choice of participle.

Babies with Anglophone parents, however, have a strong preference for past tense *spit*: according to a Google [NGram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=baby%20spat%20up%2Cbaby%20spit%20up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbaby%20spit%20up%3B%2Cc0) no infant has ever *spat up* in English, at least not in print.

Please note that these considerations do not apply to the verb *spit* as in "spit-roast." Its principle parts are *spit, spitted, spitted*.

Comment: In British English, it's definitely *spat,* whatever NGrams says.

Comment: I was surprised by the NGram, because I'm sure babies in my family spat up all the time.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of [*spat out*](https://www.google.it/search?ei=4rV8WtCWGcevU8XPnbgH&q=%22spat+out%22&oq=%22spat+out%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i10i30k1j0i7i30k1l2j0i7i10i30k1j0i7i30k1l3j0i7i10i30k1l2j0i7i30k1.3418.6557.0.6834.2.2.0.0.0.0.144.285.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.285...0j0i67k1.0.rIReSvXyYME) and babies can also [spat out](https://www.google.it/search?lr=lang_en&dcr=0&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=RrZ8WqjpKsSrUamijdAE&q=%22baby+spat+out%22&oq=%22baby+spat+out%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15509.20253.0.21288.7.7.0.0.0.0.118.785.0j7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.QrqD3msLeQM) too

Comment: Babies can spit in all directions, but as far as I know, they spit up when they vomit. I've never heard of _spit out._

Comment: _Spit_, in the sense of expectorate, is now a member of the _cut_  class of monosyllabic t-/d-final verbs with Zero affixes for past and participle: _bet
bid
burst
cast
cost
cut
fit
hit
hurt
let
put
quit
rid
set
shed
shit
shut
slit
spit
split
spread
thrust_.

Comment: Given that the various forms have coexisted since the 15th c., I think your definitive announcement may be rather premature. I personally use both past tenses.